# (Vis.js network) Incorrect node coordinates with getPositions?

Tags: javascript, popup, vis.js, vis.js-network

In my **vis.js network**, I want to make a popup appear at the position of a node when I click on the node.

I used the *getPositions* method but the popup appears in the wrong place (too much on the left and top corner), as if the coordinates were incorrect.

```
network.on("click", function (params) {
        // Get the node ID
        var nodeId = params.nodes[0];
        if (nodeId) {

            // Get the node title to show in the popup
            var popup = this.body.nodes[nodeId].options.title;

            // Get the node coordinates
            var nodePosition = network.getPositions(nodeId);
            var nodeX = nodePosition[nodeId].x;
            var nodeY = nodePosition[nodeId].y;

            // Show the tooltip in a div
            document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = popup;
            document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "block";
            // Place the div
            document.getElementById('popup').style.position = "absolute";
            document.getElementById('popup').style.top = nodeY+'px';
            document.getElementById('popup').style.left = nodeX+'px';

        }
    });
    // Empty and hide the div when click elsewhere
    network.on("deselectNode", function (params) {
        document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = null;
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none";
    });
```

Comment: For faster responses: Create a jsfiddle or something similar, so users can quickly see the problem with their own eyes.

Comment: Also, if the popup always aligns too much to the top and left cant you just account for that by added some pixels in your code? Like: style.top = 10 + nodeY + 'px'

Comment: I've just put a link in my post to see the result.
I can't add pixels in my code because every popup isn't offset by the exact same distance. I think they all have the shape of the nodes though, but it looks like they're not on the same zoom level, like my nodes are at zoom 1 and the positions of the nodes that getPositions returns is at zoom 1.5 (I don't actually have these values anywhere, it's juste an example of what it looks like).

Comment: I see it now. Please remove the link from your question again. To prevent broken links in the future. For a diagram like this its ok to include a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help on the [vis support section of github](https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/issues/155).
Turns out the trick was to use `canvasToDOM()`.

Here's how it applied to my code:

```
network.on("click", function(params) {
  // Get the node ID
  var nodeId = params.nodes[0];
  if (nodeId) {
    // Get the node title to show in the popup
    var popup = this.body.nodes[nodeId].options.title;

    // Get the node coordinates
    var { x: nodeX, y: nodeY } = network.canvasToDOM(
      network.getPositions([nodeId])[nodeId]
    );

    // Show the tooltip in a div
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
    // Place the div
    document.getElementById("popup").style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById("popup").style.top = nodeY + "px";
    document.getElementById("popup").style.left = nodeX + "px";
  }
});
```

It works when the network stays put, but in my case I want to fit the network and zoom on the clicked node, so the popup doesn't follow, but since this is a separate issue I will post another question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using network.getPositions(params.nodes[0]), but since the nodes can change a lot when zooming in and out and moving the network on the canvas somehow the positions do not match the real position of the node. I do not know if this is a bug in visjs or there is some other reason for it. The docs say they return the position of the node in the canvas space. But thats clearly not the case in your example.

Looking at the docs [ https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/#Events ] the click event argument contains:

```
{
    nodes: [Array of selected nodeIds],
    edges: [Array of selected edgeIds],
    event: [Object] original click event,
    pointer: {
        DOM: {x:pointer_x, y:pointer_y},     // << Try using this values
        canvas: {x:canvas_x, y:canvas_y}
    }
}
```

Try to use the params.pointer.DOM or params.pointer.canvas positions X and Y to position your popup. This should be the location of the cursor. This will be the same position as the node, since you clicked on it.

So try something like:

```
    document.getElementById('popup').style.top = params.pointer.DOM.y +'px';
    document.getElementById('popup').style.left = params.pointer.DOM.x +'px';
```

-- Untested

Comment: It does sound like a bug, as I also tested this in the basic example which is provided and the result is the same. I have tested your solution already, it was my plan B... it's really not ideal since I will also use the fit() function to zoom on a group of nodes when I click on a node (I just disabled it in the demo I showed in my post). So, if I make the popup appear at the pointer coordinates, it appears right where I clicked but since the view then zooms somewhere else on the canvas, the popup is no longer in the right place.

Comment: Yes, you have to think about how you want to deal with zoom and movement. Maybe hide the popup on zoom or move? But thats a different question.

Answer (score 0):

use the click event and paint a div over the canvas.

```
network.on("click", function(params) {
    // Get the node ID
    var nodeId = params.nodes[0];
    if (nodeId) {
        // Get the node title to show in the popup
        var popup = this.body.nodes[nodeId].options.title;

        //use JQUERY to see where the canvas is on the page.
        var canvasPosition = $('.vis-network').position();

        //the params give x & y relative to the edge of the canvas, not to the 
        //whole document.
        var clickX = params.pointer.DOM.x + canvasPosition.top;
        var clickY = params.pointer.DOM.y + canvasPosition.left;

        // Show the tooltip in a div
        document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
        // Place the div
        document.getElementById("popup").style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById("popup").style.top = clickY + "px";
        document.getElementById("popup").style.left = clickX + "px";
    }
});
```

[fixed position for tooltip/popup example](https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/1e626a2a-8d87-4c76-ba87-77f81540d07b/y)